# Canvas.toDataUrl() returns black image in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html2canvas

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qcnfaupL/12/

I'm trying to get an image out of a canvas, which works fine in firefox but in chrome the same code returns an empty image.

chrome:

[image]

firefox:

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I've already wasted my evening but I can't find any mentions related to this problem in chrome and equally I can't see why the code shouldn't work.

In case if it matters, I'm on Mac (Big Sur, v11.1)

Here is the full code from the fiddle above:

html:

```
<div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
    <h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4>
</div>
```

js:

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
let img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0)
let imgElement = document.createElement("img");
imgElement.src=img
console.log("img = ", img)
    document.body.append(imgElement)
});
```

Tried `setTimeout` before requesting `toDataURL` in case the image is not yet ready (even though it should be), but no luck anyway.

Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: I've tested your code on a Mac/Chrome 89 and it's working flawlessly. Maybe you're using an older html2canvas version?

Comment: @obscure crap, just tried in incognito mode and everything is working there. Thanks a lot for your help! I've also noticed that I can't open whatsapp web nor google ads account in chrome while in incognito it all works good. Seems like something is badly broken in my instance of chrome, gonna reinstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinstalling chrome fixed it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

I've noticed some other web apps didn't work in that instance of chrome neither (like whatsapp and google ads account) so something was badly broken in chrome